# Boilerplate Javascript scripts/plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, boilerplate

I've been really enjoying getting into Paul Irish's [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com) which gives best practices for html5, javascript, css and even server side stuff with the likes of a boilerplate .htaccess file. However, the Javascript file that comes is empty- for us developers to put in what we like.

I am wondering what Javascript plugins and scripts developers tend to use across all their sites? I want to create a boilerplate site that I start off with when I start building a new site. I tend to use JQuery, so scripts and plugins that use that would be useful.

Ideas that I have would be:

- [swfobject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)
- [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/)? (for sites that have video and audio) Not sure about this one
- The Fade Anything Technique
- A clear inputs script (clear any inputs when clicked)
- externalLink script (open in new tab/window when class=externalLink)
- [Break out of frame](http://usablelayout.com/articles/automatically-break-out-iframe) script

The above aren't particularly good examples, but that's why I am asking the question!

Comment: I made a html5 template generator with HTML5 Boilerplate in it and you just gave me some ideas to add :) thanks ! favorited

Comment: That sounds interesting- is this something for yourself or is it public?

Comment: That list looks like a collection of the most irritating scripts out there, that one would want to use to be "kewl" instead of being boilerplate. Why would one want to clear inputs when clicking on them? And it's **my** (the users) choice when I want to open a new tab/window.

Comment: Thanks RoToRa. This is why I am asking the question. I am sure my list of scripts is probably complete pants, and that is why I am interested in what other people use. The clear inputs script was recommended for accessibility, but do know where you are coming from. What do others think? I really want to have a list of stock scripts/plugins that would be used across most sites.

Comment: It's public but I thought posting links could be taken as spam. Anyway, admins or readers, if you think so, tell me or flag this comment as spam to be deleted. [link](http://shikiryu.com/html5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/). [yepnope.js](http://yepnopejs.com/).

With the latter, it would be good if you used this to conditionally load plugins. Also it could be an idea to use [module patterns](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth) for this boilerplate, possibly keep it namespaced.

Comment: I recommend adding `backbone.js` ontop of underscore if your doing anything non-trivial in javascript for organistation and maintenance of code.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm I am not sure if these are applicable to "all" sites. We do recommend using good [JavaScript patterns](http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/#Patterns-for-writing-better-JavaScript), but overloading a page with plugins is something I personally do not subscribe to :)

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) is one that I use on any site where I have forms. It has excellent capabilities out of the box and is very customizable and extensible.

This should be done in addition to validation on the server, of course; it's just to give nice, immediate user feedback.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have heard of this plugin, but yet to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Well It seem to be that you have confused with selecting suitable JavaScript plugins, And following a proper JavaScript pattern for coding. So what I can suggest you is to use [BoilerplateJS](http://www.boilerplatejs.org/)

[BoilerplateJS](http://www.boilerplatejs.org/) is a reference architecture which you can use as the base code to kick start your development. It is bundled with reliable plugins required for a complete product suite but the full flexibility to use your desired plugins is there.It follows industry recommended JavaScript design patterns. And as you have highlighted all these scripts and plugins can be used with jQuery.

[BoilerplateJS source code](https://github.com/ectechno/boilerplatejs)

Answer (score 0):

Great boilerplate here: https://github.com/alan345/naperg
Boilerplate for a Fullstack GraphQL App with React & Prisma